# How can I run my physical device as an emulator in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I don't even know if there is a solution for this, but seeing software like Vysor and others, I was wondering, is it possible to run my USB connected android phone as an emulator, using Android Studio for example? How can I achieve this?

Edit: I don't want to debug or run apps from android studio in my physical phone, I know I can do that. What I want is to run my phone ( with it's data, other apps installed, etc) in mt laptop, as I would with an AVD.

Comment: What does "as an emulator" mean? You can run debug apps on your device the same way you do on an emulator.

Comment: A **physical device** is never **emulated**. It's... well, **physycal**. And yes, you can use it instead of an emulator.

Comment: edited to try to clarify the question!

Answer (score 2):

yeah, you can run as a physical device on your android studio. the first thing which you have to do is go your phone settings and click on about device in that press 5-6 times on build number. after clicking on that you get a pop up that your developer mode has turned on.
in next you will see a developer options on your physical device setting.
go into developer options and click a mark on USB debugging.
after that connect your USB cable to your PC.  and open the logcat options in the android studio.
you can see that your physical device is connected to your android studio.

Answer (score 1):

yes ,
first go to mobile setting in your mobile device there you find software information

1. in software information press Build number for 5 times then it shows some toast message you are a developer
2. after that you will find developer options in settings go to it in that you will find usb debugging ( turn it on)

3)connect device with laptop using usb in and allow all the permissions that required for connection

4)go to android studio you will find your device name .If your device is not found  go to run as multiple device  there you find your  device just click it

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

Enable programmer mode on Your device and enable usb debugging there

Comment: "Developer Options" > ["USB debugging"](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#enable)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Physical device to use as a alternatives of Emulator then it is okay. You can use a Android Device to run the apps for debugging. Here is a detailed documentations how to connect your device with android Studio. 
[Check this link....](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app)